# Error when I use the function OVER(Partition by Id) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, web-hosting

I uploaded an update of my application on the server. And it threw me a problem in the query, when executing it inside MySQL, it generated the error in the incompatibility of the function `"OVER PARTITION BY ID"`

Attached small example.

My doubt is that before uploading it to the server, I was developing the application using XAMPP and at no time had it given me an error regarding the use of these functions.

In this case, I don't know what could be done about it, to find out if it is some version of the update.

I would greatly appreciate your attention and help in advance, thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does your MySQL server version is 8+? Does your client software knows about MySQL 8+ features?

Comment: In xampp i use the version 5.0.12 and this function works good. The problem it is in my hosting. But i do not know how to know the hosting's version, becaue i asked for helping, but they has not answered me yet.

Comment: *In xampp i use the version 5.0.12 and this function works good.* 5,0,12 is the version of XAMPP itself, or the version of MySQL in it?

Comment: The version of MySQL, i saw it with phpinfo()

Comment: *The version of MySQL* MySQL 5.0.12 does **NOT** support window functions. *i saw it with phpinfo()* No, provide complete output for `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: If the error says the function is not compatible with your version of MySQL, the only thing you (or anyone) can do is upgrade your version of MySQL or find a different way of writing the SQL. If your hosting service won't upgrade MySQL for you, the only choices you have is to either find that different way or find a different hosting service that supports the necessary version of MySQL. There's nothing anyone here can do with your hosting service.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help